# Sequential dispatch action in react-redux hook

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, dispatch

I am using the useDispatch() function to return me a dispatch object to fire some actions.

I have a particular scenario in which I want to fire a reject-action that cancels a user's request and after getting back the response from the server (whether it is successful or not) I will decide whether I should fire another action.

My method looks like this:

```
const reject = () => {
  dispatch(method1(data));
  dispatch(fetchAll());
}
```

When.i observe the logs on my developer's console, both `method1()` and `fetchAll()` both fires off without waiting for the response.

How do I ensure that the method1() returns some value before processing the fetchAll()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware. Take look at [Composition](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition)

> Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action. The thunk can be used to delay the dispatch of an action, or to dispatch only if a certain condition is met.

Then you can dispatch the action like this:

```js
const reject = () => {
  dispatch(method1(data)).then(res => {
    if(res.success) {
      dispatch(fetchAll());
    }
  })
}
```